# Any services that lets users create an account - for ios apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

Is there any service that lets users create an account - for ios apps?

For example, if you open the "draw something" app (or any other zynga app for example) - for the first time - they'll ask you to either create an account or login with facebook.

Instead of coding it all by myself - I'm hoping there's a service that offers this feature to developers.

Do you know about if there is any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Haven't tried it myself, but I've heard good things about [parse.com](http://parse.com).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed http://parse.com is the (new) way to go... facebook, twitter, users and anonymous users